# Visual C++ 2010 and Lapack, Blas libraries

Tags: visual-c++, lapack, blas

I want to use `Blas` and `Lapack` libraries to use some rutines, however I do not know how to use them in `Visual C++ 2010`.

How to use them in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though I haven't used it, it appears that [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) has a C++ dll interface. See [this site](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#running) - scroll down to the section titled "Part 2: Using LAPACK subroutines in a Visual (Studio) C/C++ Project".

There are pre-built Windows binaries available.

If I understand correctly, a reference version of [the BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node11.html) is included in LAPACK.

Comment: I would recommend using Armadillo, since it provides a wrapper for BLAS and LAPACK with a quite user-friendly syntax.

Answer (score 3):

If you're like me and have stopped using VS2010 and instead recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2013: here's a link to the BLAS and LAPACK dlls built for this platform. Currently only available for 64 bit though. https://bitbucket.org/aperezrathke/vs-lapack